# how to revalidate by cookie in Next.js App Router?

Tags: next.js

I have a root layout that has NavBar Component as below:

```js
export default async function NavBar() {
  const session = await getSession();
  let account = null;
  if (session) {
    account = await prisma.account.findUnique({ where: { id: session.accountId } });
  }

  return (
  // ...
```

and `getSession()` function is defined as below:

```js
export async function getSession() {
  const session = cookies().get("rim_session")?.value;
  if (!session) return null;
  return await decrypt(session);
}
```

which basicaly just get a session cookie and decrypts it. (It's a JWT)

But the problem is, even though after its expiration, when I visit any page it doesn't get re-invoked since this is a server component that does not revalidate itself unless I explicitly refresh the browser.

How can I fix this problem? Maybe using some kind of a middleware?